# Two switches in same box, on different circuits

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

Is it acceptable by US NEC standards to have two switches in a double wall box that operate on entirely different circuits in a late 50's house?

Comment: Related: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/7958/whats-the-best-way-to-label-a-double-gang-box-with-two-circuits

Comment: As long as the voltage between adjacent devices does not exceed 300 volts (NEC 404.8, 406.4), and the box fill values (NEC 314.16) are not exceeded, there should be no problem.

Comment: @Tester101 I can't even think of a home appliance that exceeds 300 volts.  I think I am okay there ;-)

Comment: @maple_shaft You are correct, it's not likely you'll have to worry about that. Just figured I'd point it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is.

As long as other requirements for wiring at met, there is no problem with two circuits (or 3, or 4!) in a box.

Consider, in fact, that code **requires** this for dishwasher and disposal installs today: Split the bridge on a receptacle and wire each outlet to a different circuit.